# Поиск между двумя датами Spring JPA Query

Tags: java, spring, запрос, дата, jpa

Пытаюсь сделать расширенный поиск по дате, контроллер получает дату и отдает в репозиторий, но ответа от туда нет.
Postman пишет что результаты по нулям, никак не могу понять в чем дело.

Я пробовал в запросе писать через between, но результат так же все по нулям.

```
z.datePost between :postDateStart and :postDateStop
```

Вот что получает контроллер

```
@GetMapping("/zakupki")
public Map<String, Object> getAllZakupki(
        @RequestParam(required = false) String mainSearch,
        @RequestParam(required = false) String orgName,
        @RequestParam(required = false) String type,
        @RequestParam(required = false) @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd.MM.yyyy") Date postDateStart,
        @RequestParam(required = false) @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd.MM.yyyy") Date postDateStop,
        @RequestParam(defaultValue = "0") int page,
        @RequestParam(defaultValue = "10") int size
) {
    List<Zakupka> content = new ArrayList<Zakupka>();
    Pageable paging = PageRequest.of(page, size);

    Page<Zakupka> pageTuts = null;

    /*if (mainSearch == null) {
        pageTuts = zakupkaRepository.findAll(paging);
    } else {
        // Спецификация для динамического поиска
        pageTuts = zakupkaRepository.findAll(search(mainSearch), paging);
    }*/

        System.out.println(postDateStart);
        System.out.println(postDateStop);
        pageTuts = zakupkaRepository.advancedSearch(orgName, type, postDateStart, postDateStop, paging);


    content = pageTuts.getContent();
    Map<String, Object> response = new HashMap<>();
    response.put("currentPage", pageTuts.getNumber());
    response.put("timeUpload", ScheduledTasks.getTime());
    response.put("totalItems", pageTuts.getTotalElements());
    response.put("totalPages", pageTuts.getTotalPages());
    response.put("content", content);

    return response;
}
```

Репозиторий

```
    @Query("select z from Zakupka z "
        + " where  (:orgName='' or lower( z.orgName) like concat( '%', lower(:orgName), '%')) "
        + "and (:type='' or lower( z.type) LIKE concat('%', lower( :type), '%'))"
        + "and (z.datePost > :postDateStart and z.datePost <  :postDateStop)")
Page<Zakupka> advancedSearch(@Param("orgName") String orgName, @Param("type") String type, @Param("postDateStart") Date postDateStart, @Param("postDateStop") Date postDateStop, Pageable page);
```

[image: Postman результаты]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Аа у меня все оказалось правильно, просто отправлял неправильный GET запрос.
Нужно было отправить не так как было указано на скриншоте, а вот так

```
http://localhost:8080/api/zakupki?orgName=&type=&postDateStart=01.01.2020&postDateStop=01.02.2021
```

И тогда все приходит нормально!